# What would be a linear program formulation of finding the maximum degree of a graph?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, optimization, linear-programming

Also, what would be a possible interpretation of the dual of this linear program? My teacher mentioned that it'd be interesting to interpret the dual but neither can I formulate the problem as an LP nor can I interpret the dual. He also said that an interesting inequality exists between the optimal of this LP, the maximum degree and the edge coloring number of a graph. I think it all points to something interesting but can't see the solution of any of these problems. Could someone help?

Comment: For undirected graphs the following should work:

1. Write down the adjacency matrix $A$ for graph $G$
2. Sum the rows or columns to get a vector $\vec d$
3. Find the Max value of $\vec d$

Comment: I wanted a linear programming formulation. Could you please post a complete answer?

Comment: What are you missing? A formulation of the row sum? You could also calculate $A^2$ and check the diagonal entries...

Comment: draks solution is nice. Indeed, the diagonal entries of $A^2$ are the degrees of your graph (provided there are no multiple edges nor loops). Out of curiosity, did your teacher give you the answer he was expecting?

Comment: But what exactly is the input here ? Is the graph already explicitely defined (with an adjacency matrix for example)?